# Django - Initial form field values not showing

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-views

### I am trying to set the initial value of a form field.

I have approached it the following ways:

#### forms.py:

```
class FilterGigsForm(forms.Form):

    field = forms.IntegerField(label="", required=False, initial=5)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
        kwargs.update(initial={
            'field': 5,
        })
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field'].initial = 5
```

#### views.py

```
class HomePage(FormMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyForm
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = MyForm(self.request.GET, initial={'field': 5,})
     ...
        return render(request, 'index.html', {"form": form, })
```

I have loaded the form field into my **template** as follows:

```
<div class="styling">
    {{ form.field|as_crispy_field }}
</div>
```

However, none of these approaches are working and the initial value is not showing when I load/reload the page.

Comment: What is you just do this: ```form = MyForm(initial={'field': 5,})```

Comment: yeah that worked. Removing the self.request.GET part was causing the issue. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I've published the answer then, please consider upvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form = MyForm(initial={'field': 5,})`